# How do I create a custom Grails script in Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, scripting

In Grails 2.4 I used to put them in the grails/script directory. I don't see it Grails 3

Comment: I got my own scripts for scafolding, I'm about to review then I'll share them in github. Thanks in advance for your help !    :0)

Comment: You should add this comment in your question, it'll be more visible

Comment: See the grails docs https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-script.html

Comment: Yes u r right !! things works pretty different in Grails 3. That link sent me to other page **http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/api/org/grails/cli/profile/commands/templates/TemplateRenderer.html**. The *TemplateRenderes* is the code generation "engine" - some thinh new 2 learn today !